# Want to merge image with output of synaescope in gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I am using synaescope to display some music visualization on my raspberry pi.

Is there some sort of image merge function in gstreamer. I'd like to have synaescope to write on top of an image.  Possibly have all black pixels replaced with an image for the output of synaescope.

Just as a reference my full pipeline looks like this. (

```
gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! tee name=t ! queue ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink t. ! queue ! audioconvert ! synaescope ! video/x-raw,width=1000,height=400,pattern-aspect-ratio=1/1 ! videoconvert ! fbdevsink
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **compositor** element such as:

```
gst-launch-1.0 \
compositor name=comp \
  sink_0::xpos=0  sink_0::ypos=0  sink_0::width=1200 sink_0::height=600 sink_0::zorder = 0 \
  sink_1::xpos=50 sink_1::ypos=50 sink_1::width=1000 sink_1::height=400 sink_1::zorder = 1 \
  ! videoconvert ! autovideosink \
videotestsrc pattern=ball ! video/x-raw,width=1200,height=600 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=RGBA ! queue ! comp.sink_0 \
audiotestsrc ! tee name=t \
  t. ! queue ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink \
  t. ! queue ! audioconvert ! synaescope ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx,width=1000,height=400,pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1 ! alpha method=custom target-r=0 target-b=0 target-g=0 black-sensitivity=128 white-sensitivity=0 ! video/x-raw,format=RGBA ! queue ! comp.sink_1
```